# .net repeater with child repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have the following asp.net repeater with a child repeater

```
<asp:Repeater ID="MainAccordianRepeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" class="mainAccordLink" href="#collapse<%# Eval("catId").ToString() %>">
            <%# Eval("catDesc").ToString() %>
            </a>
            <input type="button" value="<%# Eval("btnTxt").ToString() %>" onclick="Confirm('<%# Eval("statusFunction").ToString() %>root','<%# Eval("catId").ToString() %>')" class="<%# Eval("statusFunction").ToString() %> btn" id="rootbutton<%# Eval("catId").ToString() %>" />
        </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse<%# Eval("catId").ToString() %>" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <ul id="childUl<%# Eval("catId").ToString() %>" class="childRepeater_DataBinding">
            <asp:Repeater ID="childRepeater" runat="server" OnDataBinding="ChildCats_DataBinding" />

            </asp:Repeater>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

and this is the code that should populate the repeater and it's child

```
protected void GetRootCategories()
{
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStr))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spR_GetRootCategories", con))
    {
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    MainAccordianRepeater.DataSource = reader;
    MainAccordianRepeater.DataBind();
    con.Close();
    }
}
}
protected void ChildCats_DataBinding(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
Repeater rep = (Repeater)(sender);

int parentCatId = (int)(Eval("catId"));
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStr))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spR_GetChildCategories", con))
    {
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParentId", parentCatId);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    //rep.DataSource = rdr;
    //rep.DataBind();
    con.Close();
    }
}
}
```

the problem is when ever I uncomment these two lines

```
    //rep.DataSource = rdr;
    //rep.DataBind();
```

it crashes with the error

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.
```

can anyone help me out

I have modified the code to this

```
protected void ChildCats_DataBinding(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Repeater rep = (Repeater)(sender);

    int parentCatId = (int)(Eval("catId"));
    DataSet ChildCatsDs = new DataSet();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spR_GetChildCategories", con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParentId", parentCatId);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter cCats = new SqlDataAdapter();
            cCats.SelectCommand = cmd;
            cCats.Fill(ChildCatsDs);
            //SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            rep.DataSource = ChildCatsDs;
            rep.DataBind();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

but it just gives the exact same outcome

I have just modified it again to this

```
protected void ChildCats_DataBinding(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Repeater rep = (Repeater)(sender);

    int parentCatId = (int)(Eval("catId"));
    DataSet ChildCatsDs = new DataSet();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spR_GetChildCategories", con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParentId", parentCatId);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter cCats = new SqlDataAdapter();
            cCats.SelectCommand = cmd;
            cCats.Fill(ChildCatsDs);
            //SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            //rep.DataSource = ChildCatsDs;
            //rep.DataBind();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("catId");
    dt.Columns.Add("parentId");
    dt.Columns.Add("catDesc");
    dt.Columns.Add("status");
    dt.Columns.Add("statusFunction");
    dt.Columns.Add("btnTxt");
    dt.Columns.Add("disabled");
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["catId"] = 83;
    dr["parentId"] = 72;
    dr["catDesc"] = "orange";
    dr["status"] = "0";
    dr["statusFunction"] = "enable";
    dr["btnTxt"] = "activate";
    dr["disabled"] = "t";
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    rep.DataSource = dt;
    rep.DataBind();
}
```

and the page just times out

Comment: The problem is with the connection to the database. Check the connection string. Increase the timeout and then see how it goes.

Comment: What happens if you don't use the `SqlDataReader` but a `DataTable` as datasource? The latter is offline whereas the former is a stream to the database. You can use `new SqlDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(table)`

Comment: Why don't you try to use the `ItemDataBound` event to bind the data in the child repeat?

Comment: Have you got an example of how to use the ItemDataBound event

Answer (score 1):

you should bind the child repeater based on ItemDataBoundEvent of parent repeater . Try like given below

```
protected void MainAccordianRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

        Repeater rep = e.Item.FindControl("childRepeater") as Repeater;

        int parentCatId = (int)(Eval("catId"));
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spR_GetChildCategories", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParentId", parentCatId);
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                rep.DataSource = rdr;
                rep.DataBind();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: have you added an event to parent repeater ? something like this
<asp:Repeater ID="MainAccordianRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="MainAccordianRepeater_ItemDataBound">

Comment: try to bind an event , like I provided above , for your case. if it seems helpful then please accept my answer